# How does java determine if there is an apparent deadlock?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a test unit to measure the correctness of a lift controller class, which simulate people going in and out and lift door opening and closing.

My problem is that, everyone time out of my 10 test, one or two will invoke the following failure:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apparent deadlock
thread 1 WAITING
  java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
  lift.MyLiftController.callLift(MyLiftController.java:23)
  lift.MyLiftControllerMultithreadedTest1.thread1(MyLiftControllerMultithreadedTest1.java:29)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  edu.umd.cs.mtc.TestFramework$2.run(TestFramework.java:592)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

    at edu.umd.cs.mtc.TestFramework$1.run(TestFramework.java:483)
```

Sometimes, it will say something like this:

```
Exception in thread "thread 2" java.lang.AssertionError: thread 2 killed by thread 1
```

Therefore my question is:

> **When will Java determine whether a process is an apparent deadlock?**

Here is snippets of relevant code:

## TestLifeMultiple1.java

#### This is the test, run 100 times

```
@Test
    public void testLiftMultiple1() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("TEST 1: MULTIPLE TIMES TO DETECT INTERMITTENT FAILURES.");
        TestFramework.runManyTimes( new MyLiftControllerMultithreadedTest1(),100);
    }
```

## MyLiftControllerMultithreadedTest2.java

#### This is the actual content of the test

```
// Person thread 1.
public void thread1() throws InterruptedException {

    // Person calls the lift to floor 4, going UP.
    lift_controller.callLift(4, LiftController.Direction.UP);

    // Person thread should only be here when tick 2 has occurred ...
    // since this indicates the lift thread has actually opened the doors.
    assertTick(2);
}

// Person thread 2.
public void thread2() throws InterruptedException {
  // same as thread 1
}

public void thread3() throws InterruptedException {

    // Force Lift thread to wait until person threads are blocked,
    // and the different person threads have called the lift.
    waitForTick(1);

    for (int level = 0; level < 4; level++) {
        // Level 0,1,2 and 3 ... should not open doors ... hence return False.
        Assert.assertFalse(lift_controller.liftAtFloor(level, LiftController.Direction.UP));
    }

    // Level 4 ... should open doors ... hence return True.
    Assert.assertTrue(lift_controller.liftAtFloor(4, LiftController.Direction.UP));

    //.....similar stuff

    // Open the doors even if incorrect previous assertion ...
    lift_controller.doorsOpen(7);
    lift_controller.doorsClosed(7);
}
```

## MyLiftController.java

```
/* Interface for People */
public synchronized void callLift(int floor, Direction direction) throws InterruptedException {
    numOfPplAtFlrInDir[floor][direction2Int(direction)] ++;

    // Person can only enter when they are on the right floor towards right direction, 
    while (floor != currentFloor || direction != currentDirection){
        wait(); 
    }

    numOfPplAtFlrInDir[floor][direction2Int(direction)] --;
    if (numOfPplAtFlrInDir[floor][direction2Int(direction)] == 0) {
        notify();
    }

    debug("Someone has entered "+floor);
}
```

The following code is also in MyLiftController, it is used to set currentFloor and currentDirection. But as you can see, is called on thread 3:

```
/* Interface for Lifts */
public synchronized boolean liftAtFloor(int floor, Direction direction) {
        currentFloor = floor;
        currentDirection = direction;

        //if there are people who will get in or out at floor X in direction Y
        if (numOfPplAtFlrInDir[floor][direction2Int(direction)]!=0 || numOfPplAtFlr[floor]!=0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}

// door waits indefinitely until all people exit or enter
public synchronized void doorsOpen(int floor) throws InterruptedException {

    // ask everyone to take action and wait for them to finish
    notifyAll();
    while (numOfPplAtFlrInDir[floor][direction2Int(currentDirection)]!=0 && numOfPplAtFlr[floor]!=0){
        wait(); 
    }

}

// while door is closed, no one is allowed to enter again 
// (they will be waiting)
public void doorsClosed(int floor) {
    debug("door is closed at "+floor);
    //next round will start
}
```

All I want to know is why, my tests fail randomly. How does Java determine if there is an apparent deadlock? Thank you so much!

EDIT:

Ops, I did not post my doorsOpen and doorsClose function. Basically, both wait() will eventually be notified by doorsOpen function. Does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Java who's determining that. It's the [MultithreadedTC](https://code.google.com/p/multithreadedtc/) framework you're using.

As for your bug, when your two threads have gone to `wait()`, there's no-one to `notify()` them anymore. Your thread-3 could be doing it, but now it's just setting some variables and not bothering notifying any waiting threads.

Comment: Thank you at first! However, I think I missed posting my doorsOpen function which will be called in the mid of the test, eventually notifyAll() the wait(). liftAtFloor is just to update the current floor. My mistake. Will this allow you to figure out the problem here again? I clicked into MultithreadedTC link, but couldnt find any helpful resource that explains why one thread killed another one

Comment: Hard to say since it's a 3rd party framework. You should look into its configuration. There's no surefire way to detect a deadlock, so that can easily be a false positive.